# SQL Fiddle threw "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'."

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I was practicing how to make databases using SQL and computer threw `CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'`. I don't know what i'm doing wrong here, I can't edit any of the settings since I ran the query below in an online ide.

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE DATABASE Contacts
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create new databases through SQL Fiddle. It already runs your code in a new database. If you want to practice creating new databases, I would suggest SQL Server Express, https://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/database.aspx .